# Splitting of conjugacy class of an element

Tags: abstract-algebra, group-theory

Let $G$ be a finite Group, H be a subgroup of $G$ of index $2$, and $x\in H$. Denote by $cl_G(x)$ conjugacy class of $x$ in G and by $cl_H(x)$ the conjugacy class of $x$ in $H$.

Question is :

$(a)$ Show that if $C_G(x)\leq H$, then $|cl_H(x)|=\frac{1}{2}|cl_G(x)|$.

$(b)$ Show that if $C_G(x)$ is not contained in $H$ then, $|cl_H(x)|=|cl_G(x)|$.

What I have done so far is,

Denoting $C_H(x)$ as Centralizer of $x$ in $H$ and by $C_G(x)$ Centralizer of $x$ in $G$

we have by orbit stabilizer theorem, $|cl_H(x)|=|\frac{H}{C_H(x)}|$ and $|cl_G(x)|=|\frac{G}{C_G(x)}|$.

As $C_H(x)=\{g\in H : gx=xg \}$ and $C_G(x)=\{g\in G : gx=xg \}$  we have $C_G(x)=C_H(x)\cap H$

Now, $|cl_H(x)|=|\frac{H}{C_H(x)}|=|\frac{H}{C_G(x)\cap H}|$

Assuming $C_G(x)\leq H$ we see that, $|cl_H(x)|=|\frac{H}{C_H(x)}|=|\frac{H}{C_G(x)\cap H}|=|\frac{H}{C_G(x)}|$.

we have $|\frac{H}{C_G(x)}|=\frac{1}{2}|\frac{G}{H}|.|\frac{H}{C_G(x)}|=\frac{1}{2}|\frac{G}{C_G(x)}|=\frac{1}{2}|cl_G(x)|$ i.e., $|cl_H(x)|=\frac{1}{2}|cl_G(x)|$.

So, I guess I am Done in case of $C_G(x)\leq H$. (If there are any gaps, please feel free to inform me).

Now the Problem is with the case of $C_G(x)$ not contained in $H$.

In this case i am unable to show that $|\frac{H}{C_G(x)\cap H}|=|\frac{G}{C_G(x)}|$.

I am very sure that I am missing a small argument. But No idea :(

Any help would be appreciated.

Thank You.

P.S $1$: I would appreciate if someone can fix a better title for this :)

P.S $2$: Even before this there is an exercise (which i have not solved)

"Let H be a subgroup of $G$ of index $2$ and let $g$ be an element of $H$. Show that,

if $C_G(g)\subset H$ then he conjugacy class of $g$ "splits" into two conjugacy classes in $H$ and if $C_G(x)\not\subset H$ then  the class of $g$ remains the class of $g$ in $H$."

I see that "$P.S :2$" and the titled Question are one and the same, But then why would he ask it again :O. Am I Missing something?

P.S $3$ : Actual Intention is to check for splitting of Conjugacy classes of elements of $A_5$. I like Mathematics just because of this reason. You want to solve some problem, you have the possibility of going for a less complicated problem and then try to generalize.

All these sayings matter only when I get the answer :P

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Since $H$ is index two, $G$ is $H  \cup yH$ for any other element $ y \in G-H$, in particular if $y \in C_G(x)-H$ then we get $C_G(x) = C_H(x) \cup yC_H(x)$. So $|C_G(x)| = 2|C_H(x)|$ which implies $|cl_H(x)|=|cl_G(x)|$ as desired.

Answer (score 4):

Since $H$ is of index $2$, $H$ is normal in $G$ and there is a group homomorphism $s : G \to \Bbb Z/2\Bbb Z$ such that $s(x) = 0 \iff x \in H$.

If $C$ is a subgroup of $G$, we look at the restriction $s'$ of $s$ to $C$.
Its kernel is $C \cap H$ and its image is a subgroup of $\Bbb Z/2\Bbb Z$ .

Since $|C| = |\ker s'| * |\operatorname{im} \, s'|$,
 either the image is $\{0\}$, and $|H \cap C |= |C|$, so that $C \subset H$,
either the image is $\{0;1\}$, and $|H\cap C| = |C|/2$.

Now apply this with $C = C_G(x)$ and $C \cap H = C_H(x)$.