# Index of centralizer of alternating group

Tags: group-theory, finite-groups, symmetric-groups, permutations

For any element $x \in A_5$, we have that $$[A_5:C_{A_5}(x)]=\begin{cases}
[S_5:C_{S_5}(x)], & \text{condition 1} \\
\frac{1}{2}[S_5:C_{S_5}(x)], & \text{condition 2}
\end{cases}$$

Basically, I want to know what the conditions are. Note that $C$ is the centralizer $C_G(x)$. Thanks.

Comment: Condition 1 is $C_{S_5}(x) \nsubseteq A_5$, and condition 2 is $C_{S_5}(x) \subset A_5$. Can you try proving this now?

Comment: http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/478157/splitting-of-conjugacy-class-of-an-element... I hope this would help you... :)